# LFS (Linux From Scratch) hard disk partition requirement

Tags: linux, partition, lfs

I am going through the LFS documentation in order to build my flavor of firmware for our systems. Currently my host machine is Ubuntu 18.10. I have 2 hard drives `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. My Ubuntu system is running on `/dev/sda` which is 240 GB SSD. My `/dev/sdb` is 1 TB wheres I am using it as my data disk and having lot of free space.

Here I have some question.

1. Do I need to do the partition in second drive for LFS?
2. Is it OK to create necessary partitions for LFS from the free space of `/dev/sdb` without clearing the whole data on that disk?
3. Ubuntu has the `/bin/sh` linked to `/bin/dash` wheres the LFS requirement says `/bin/sh -> /bin/bash`. Do I need to change this link or can I ignore this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do I need to do the partition in second drive for LFS?

> The recommended approach to building an LFS system is to use an
>   available empty partition or, if you have enough unpartitioned space,
>   to create one. Source: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/creatingpartition.html

It doesn't matter on which drive the partition is located.

### Is it OK to create necessary partitions for LFS from the free space of `/dev/sdb`

Yes.

### Ubuntu has the /bin/sh linked to /bin/dash wheres the LFS requirement says /bin/sh -> /bin/bash. Do I need to change this link or can I ignore this part?

> Note that the symlinks mentioned above are required to build an LFS
>   system using the instructions contained within this book. *Symlinks
>   that point to other software (such as dash, mawk, etc.) may work, but
>   are not tested or supported by the LFS development team*, and may
>   require either deviation from the instructions or additional patches
>   to some packages. Source: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/hostreqs.html

I recommend creating a virtual machine and using it as your LFS host. That way, you can do whatever you need to do to the "host" without potentially damaging your real host.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to resolve the issue you have marked #3 is to run:

`sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh`

to change back when you finish your LFS build just run:

`sudo ln -sf dash /bin/sh`